# Avoid while loop to check row "state change"

Tags: sql-server, database

I have a table that stores an Id, a datetime and an int crescent value. This value increases until it "breaks" and returns to a 0-near value. Ex: ...1000, 1200, 1350, 8, 10, 25...
I need to count how many times this "overflow" happens, BUT... I'm talking about a table that stores 200k rows per day!
I had already solved it! But using a procedure with a cursor that iterates over it with a while-loop. But I KNOW it isn't the faster way to do it.

Can someone help me to find some another way?
Thanks!

->

Table structure:
Id Bigint Primary Key, CreatedAt DateTime, Value Not Null Int.

Problem:
If Delta-Value between two consecutive rows is < 0, increase a counter.
Table has 200k new rows every-day.
No trigger allowed.

---

[FIRST EDIT]

```
Table has the actual structure:
    CREATE TABLE ValuesLog (
    Id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY, 
    Machine BIGINT, 
    CreatedAt DATETIME,
    Value INT
)
```

I need:
To check when the [Value] of some [Machine] suddenly decreases.

Some users said to used LEAD/LAG. But it has a problem... if I chose many machines, the LEAD/LAG fuctions doesn't care about "what machine it is". So, if I find for machine-1 and machine-2, if machine-1 increase but the machine-2 descrease, LEAD/LAG will give me a false positive.

So, how my table actually looks:
[Many rows of the actual table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JuFqh.png)

(The image above are selecting for 3 ou 4 machines. But, IN THIS EXAMPLE, the machines are not messed up. But can occurs! And in this case, LEAD/LAG doesn't care if the line above are machine-1 or machine-2)

What I want:
In that line 85, the [value] breaks and restart. Id like to count every occorrence when it happens, the selected machines.
So:
"Machine-1 restarted 6 times... Machine-9 restarted 10 times..."

I had done something LIKE this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CountProduction @Machine INT_ARRAY READONLY, @Start DATETIME, @End DATETIME AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    -- Declare counter and insert start values
    DECLARE @Counter TABLE(
        machine INT PRIMARY KEY, 
        lastValue BIGINT DEFAULT 0, 
        count BIGINT DEFAULT 0
    )
    INSERT INTO @Counter(machine) SELECT n FROM @Machine

    -- Declare cursor to iteract over results of values log
    DECLARE valueCursor CURSOR LOCAL FOR 
        SELECT
            Value,
            Aux.LastValue,
            Aux.count
        FROM
            ValueLog,
            @Machine AS Machine,
            @Counter AS Counter
        WHERE
            ValueLog.Machine = Machine.n
            AND Counter.machine = ValueLog.Machine
            AND ValueLog.DateCreate BETWEEN @Start AND @End;

    -- Start iteration
    OPEN valueCursor
    DECLARE @RowMachine INT
    DECLARE @RowValue BIGINT
    DECLARE @RowLastValue BIGINT
    DECLARE @RowCount BIGINT
    FETCH NEXT FROM valueCursor INTO @RowMachine, @RowValue, @RowLastValue, @RowCount

    -- Iteration
    DECLARE @increment INT
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        IF @RowValue < @RowLastValue
            SET @increment = 1
        ELSE
            SET @increment = 0

        -- Update counters
        UPDATE 
            @Counter
        SET
            lastValue = @RowValue,
            count = count + @increment
        WHERE
            inj = @RowMachine

        -- Proceed to iteration
        FETCH NEXT FROM valueCursor INTO @RowMachine, @RowValue, @RowLastValue, @RowCount
    END

    -- Closing iteration
    CLOSE valueCursor
    DEALLOCATE valueCursor

    SELECT machine, count FROM @Counter
```

Comment: `LAG` and `LEAD` are your friends.

Comment: Request you to format your question in nice way and also include sample data, your code what you have tried and expected output data.

Comment: `LEAD` and `LAG` allow `OVER (PARTITION BY ..)` clauses to solve exactly the problem you mention.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I think it can really help. I'll try it. thanks.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, thanks! I tried something like you said. And reduced from 5 minutes request to a 23 seconds.
I answered with the final code.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use LEAD(). If the next row < current row, count that occurrence.

Comment: I used it before. But it has some "strange behaviors". I created a view to speed-up the code. But when I call it, the LEAD/LAG functions, it mess up the final content.
So, my second trying was with a procedure. It works! but it takes a lot of time.

Comment: Perhaps you should have started by posting the code for that `VIEW` @DarthÇeqüella. ;)

Comment: When I said "speed-up" are not the DB. But another developers can use the View until re-work. So I created the view to speed-up THE CODE [development], not the query.  

@Larnu I eddited.

Comment: @DarthÇeqüella I don't see any DDL in your post.

Answer (score 0):

Solved using @jeroen-mostert suggested

```
DECLARE @Start DATETIME
DECLARE @End DATETIME

SET @Start = '2019-01-01'
SET @End = GETDATE()

SELECT 
    Machine, 
    COUNT(DeltaValue) AS Prod
FROM
    (SELECT
        Log.Machine,
        Log.Value - LAG(Log.Value) OVER (PARTITION BY Log.Machine ORDER BY Log.Id) AS DeltaValue
    FROM
        ValueLog AS Log,
        (SELECT
            Id,
            Machine,
            Value
        FROM
            ValueLog
        ) AS AuxLog
    WHERE
        AuxLog.Id = Log.Id
        AND Proto.DateCreate BETWEEN @Start AND @End
        AND Proto.Machine IN (1, 9, 10)
        ) as TB1
WHERE
    DeltaValue < 0
GROUP BY
    Machine
ORDER BY
    Machine
```

In this case, the inner LAG/LEAD function didn't mess up the content (what happened for some reason when I created a view... I'll try to understand later).

Thanks everybody! I'm new at DB, and this question make me crazy for a whole day.